# Determine the matrix of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $B=\{b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4,b_5 \}$ be a basis for vector space. Note that: $b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4$ and $b_5$ all are vector. Let $f(b_1)=b_2, f(b_2)=b_1, f(b_3)=b_2+b_3, f(b_4)=0$ and $f(b_5)=b_5$. Let $f'$ be the linear extension of $f$ to all of the vector space. Give the matrix representation of $f'$ for $B \rightarrow B$.

Comment: you must show your work. also, this question has been asked dozens of times on this site.

Comment: I could not find this question on site after your answer can you give link of this question please ?